# How to get empty cells rows in mssql

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have been trying to get the rows where cell is empty but how can i get an empty cell
Its not NULL over there, its like an empty string.

```
05J9LJ-E    E004030 BGH/F.TB
            E004032 000080.KS
002X87-E    E004033 018880.KS
```

So second row, first column is like 8 spaces so how can i get these rows

> SELECT column_A,column_B,column_C   FROM [dbo].[table] where column_A
>   is null
>
> SELECT column_A,column_B,column_C   FROM [dbo].[table] where column_A
>   = ''

When i put the data[image: Notepad View] in notepad++

Comment: The syntax is clearly SQL Server so I removed the mysql tag.

Answer (score 1):

You can check if they are `NULL` or spaces by using an `OR` between both conditions:

```
WHERE column_A IS NULL
  OR  column_A = ''  -- includes multiple spaces
```

Comment: i tried it but its not working, may be there are some extra characters in between

Comment: LTRIM(RTRIM(column_A)) = '', isn't that exactly the same as column_A = '' ?

Comment: @t-clausen.dk: you're right :) Edited my answer to take it into account.

Answer (score 1):

You can check that there are no non-space characters in the value:

```
SELECT column_A, column_B, column_C
FROM [dbo].[table] 
WHERE column_A is null OR
      column_A NOT LIKE '%[^ ]%'
```

This has the advantage that you can include other characters besides spaces, if you need to.